# Pandas shows SettingWithCopyWarning when a column is integers/boolean, Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boolean

I have the following codes with Pandas packages on Python 3.

```
import pandas as pd

def run(df_raw):
    df = df_raw
    mask = df['C'].idxmax()
    df_max = df.loc[mask]
    df_max['mask by maximum C'] = mask
    return df_max

def main():
    data = {
            'A': [1, 2],  # 'A' contains integers
            'B': [1, 0],  # 'B' contains boolean
            # 'B': [1., 0],  # 'B' contains floats
            'C': [0.520073, 0.544790]  # 'C' contains floats
            }

    df_raw = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_raw = df_raw.set_index(['A'])

    df_max = run(df_raw)

    print(df_max)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the column 'B', if it is boolean, the SettingWithCopyWarning will show, regarding to the code

```
df_max['mask by maximum C'] = mask
```

The full message of the warning is:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df_max['mask by maximum C'] = mask
C:\Users\lei.wu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:747: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.loc[key] = value
```

But when I change the column 'B' to be floats, no warning is shown.

Do you know what the reason is? Thanks

Comment: did you read the links to the documentation provided by the warning? what wasn't clear about them?

Comment: @PaulH, good question. I have read it, but the document says something about chained-indexing. But in my case, there is no chained index, only "boolean or float" can make a difference.

Comment: hint: add `assert not df_max._is_view` to the `run` function

Comment: @PaulH, thanks, I added it to the run function, but I still got the warning.

Comment: the point is that `df_max` is a view. So `df_max[<column>]` is chained

Comment: @PaulH, but why no warnings when elements in column 'B' are floats? Changing the type from boolean to float will not change whether df_max is view or not.

Comment: it should probably fire for both settings. either way, unchaining the assignment removes the warning

Comment: @PaulH, I see the reason. When 'B' is boolean, df_max is not a view, but if 'B' is float, df_max is a view. Maybe it is because of some internal settings in Pandas. Anyhow, if I added `df_max = df_max.to_frame()` after `df_max` is defined, it is sure that it is not a view. Thanks for your help.